# I'm struggling to make exe file using pyinsatller in python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I made "exe" file using pyinstaller .

(command in cmd window : **pyinstaller -w -F test.py**  and using many command)

It worked fine when I ran it before, but since I started writing a new Python file,
The "exe" file have problems.

files are generated well, but when I run this "exe" program.

error window pop up like this : **python failed to execute script test.py**

I looked for this problem all the web, but I couldn't find how to fix it

i'm using PYQT5 gui program, but there is no image

and

3.6.1 versino python 32bit

Answer (score 0):

if you add new changes, try to delete the files generated on your first run of creating the .exe and try again with a clean folder structure